# How to get shipping charge in DHL

Tags: api, dhl

- I cant able to get `shipping charge` in DHL.
- I know that shipping charge is only get when rated is `Yes` and service is `dutiable` in `PLT` service.
- But my question is without using `dutiable` or `non-dutiable` how can I get shipping charge.

TECHNICALLY

- In request XML if put below tag then and then only get the response so without `Y` get shipping charge please guide me, actually which thing change response XML or any other tag that not getting so please help me for that..

  ```
   <IsDutiable>Y</IsDutiable>   --  GET SHIPPING CHARGE
   <IsDutiable>N</IsDutiable>   --  NOT GET SHIPPING CHARGE(required with this tag)
  ```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: no steel same preoblem

Comment: Which service are you calling? GetQuote or GetCapability?